# Aren't all data exchanges through a webserver vulnerable to interception?

Tags: security, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

As far as encryption protocols go, Whisper Systems has the gold standard - but ultimately, if you had complete access to the server, couldn't you just intercept the very first exchange (of keys) and create a man-in-the-middle receiver and sender to both parties?

After keys have been exchanged, then all future exchanges sent to the server are encrypted (and so interception at that point is not a major concern) - but my question is really about that first key exchange: Isn't that an inescapable vulnerability for anything passing through external equipment (short of meeting people and confirming keys in person)?

Comment: No, this is a very naive approach, cryptography is much more complex than that. However, I think this belongs more to [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "if you had complete access to the server" is a high claim. But indeed, you would then not need to 'break' any encryption anymore.

Comment: I am sure I'm oversimplifying the situation, so please forgive me; but my understanding of the strength of the Whisper protocol was that is designed to be secure even in compromised servers - but just doesn't make sense if the owners of the server were watching an account/ip/id and put a man-in-the-middle script targeting any new exchanges going from or to said account?

Comment: Just one example to provide a tiny bit of insight. Consider Alice and Bob, wanting to talk securely for which they need a shared key that they don't have. Alice comes up with primes `p` and `g`, sends them to Bob. Alice creates secret random `a` and computes A=g^a mod p, sends A to Bob. Bob creates secret random `b`, computes B=g^b mod p, sends B to Alice. Alice computes k = B^a mod p, Bob computes k = A^b mod p. They both have the same key `k`, but due to math (discrete logarithm is NP-complete), an attacker that observed traffic cannot compute k (ie. it takes very long if `p` is large).